# Dropdown getting only two value from xml file

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I Am trying to add data into a combo box named combo_assembly using Ajax..

The Function is:

```
function populate_combo_assembly(xmlindata) {
var xmldata = xmlindata.getElementsByTagName('Assemblies');
    if(xmldata.length <= 0) {
    alert("Data Unavailable");
        return;
    }
    window.document.getElementById('combo_assembly').options.length = 0;
    var firstOption = new Option('--Please select--', '', false, false);
    window.document.getElementById('combo_assembly').options.add(firstOption);
    for(var i =0; i <= xmldata.length; i++) {
        var typename = '';
        var x,y;
        x = xmlindata.getElementsByTagName('name')[i];
        y = x.childNodes[0];
        typename = y.nodeValue;
        var newOption = new Option(typename, typename, false, false);
        window.document.getElementById('combo_assembly').options.add(newOption);

    }

    window.document.getElementById('combo_assembly').disabled = false;  
}
```

And taking The values from a file..Code is:

```
<?php

include("database/dbconfig.inc.php");

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
echo "<Assemblies>\n";
$select = "SELECT * FROM assembly";
try {
    foreach($dbh->query($select) as $row) {
        echo "<Assembly>\n<name>".$row['name']."</name>\n<id>".$row['id']."</id>\n<category>".$row['category']."</category>\n</Assembly>\n";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
echo "</Assemblies>";
?>
```

THe problem is that this xml file is taking all the contents I from the database table. But  the function is taking only the first two values from the xml code. 
The Output of xml file

```
<Assemblies>
<Assembly>
<name>total</name>
<id>A00000</id>
<category>Brake</category>
</Assembly>
<Assembly>
<name>asd</name>
<id>A00001</id>
<category>Brake</category>
</Assembly>
<Assembly>
<name>ga</name>
<id>ga</id>
<category>Suspension</category>
</Assembly>
<Assembly>
<name>65</name>
<id>r00</id>
<category>Brake</category>
</Assembly>
<Assembly>
<name>yty</name>
<id>tyt</id>
<category>Suspension</category>
</Assembly>
<Assembly>
<name>Gaurav</name>
<id>Z0012</id>
<category>Brake</category>
</Assembly>
</Assemblies>
```

Thanks In advance for help.

Comment: can you post up the resulting XML from your 2nd page please?

Comment: i have edited my question with the xml result u wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the xmldata as

`var xmldata = xmlindata.getElementsByTagName('Assemblies');`

Shouldn't that be

`var xmldata = xmlindata.getElementsByTagName('Assembly');`

As the information is not contained in the wrapper element .

Comment: as far as i know..i think i should put the main tag over there instead of the sub-tag..right?.Assemblies is the main tag of whole xml and assembly is another tag coming inside Assemblies tag

Comment: Oh yeah, you already get the childnode in the for loop (which shouldn't be necessary if you get the xmldata by requesting 'Assembly' in stead of 'Assemblies').

Comment: oh...thanks for that..i will look into that..but that won't solve what I have posted above  right?

Comment: By the way, you might want to take a look at [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). It makes navigating XML structures quite a lot more readable.